# Criar algoritmo que calcule LOG no visualg

Tags: matemática, visualg

Foi me passado uma lista de exercícios para fazer em VisuAlg e estou com dúvida em um desses exercícios:

> "Entrar com o número e a base em que se deseja calcular o logaritmo desse número e imprimi-lo."

Eu sei que tem uma função que calcula logaritmos na base 10(LOG) mais não faço ideia de como calcular logaritmo sem ser na base 10.

Answer (score 0):

Matematicamente:

```
log b(x) = log k(x) / log k(b)
```

onde b e k são bases.

Assim log de x na base 2 no VisuAlg seria:

```
log(x) / log(2)
```